# Is there a source for Pidyon Haben seuda equivalent to 84 fasts?

Tags: sources-mekorot, fast-days, pidyon-haben

In [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71313/17563), @Motel quotes an oft-quoted idea that partaking of a *seudas Pidyon Haben* is equivalent to fasting for 84 days. This is fabled to be alluded to in the words 'פדיום' (Bamidbar 3:49), which can be split to פ"ד יום.

Is there any source for this concept?

Answer (score 5):

This idea is quoted by the [Sdei Chemed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Hezekiah_Medini) ([*Mareches Samech, Klal 54*](https://simla.otzar.org/download/file.php?id=993&sid=0d899742c0c49197516cadabbe4149e7)) who relates of an incident where he declined an invitation to a *pidyon haben* in Jerusalem in the year 5659. In response, he was told of this idea - that the *seudas pidyon haben* is equivalent to fasting for 84 days - and writes that he doesn't know of any source for this, and that he believes it has no source. [The Sdei Chemed is famous for his encyclopedic knowledge of obscure sefarim.]

> בשדי חמד ח״ה כלל נ״ד, עמ׳ 208: בשנת תרנ״ט בהיותי בעיר הקודש ירושלים,
> הזמינו אותי על פדיון הבן ולא הלכתי, ואמרו לי שיש בספרים דסעודת פדיון
> הבן עולה במקום פ״ד תעניות, ואני לא הייתי יודע דבר זה.  שוב ראיתי בשו"ת הד"ר בסימן ט"ל דף ס"ה סוף עמוד א´ שכתב שהעולם אומרים שסעודת פדיון הבן עולה במקום פ"ד תעניות כמנין אחה"ע כמו שמתענים בימי השובבי"ם עד כאן לשונו. ונראה שאין מקור
> לדבר הזה, רק שיחה נאה בפי הבריאות׳.

It is told that when the sages of Jerusalem found this in the Sdei Chemed, they were astounded that there was no source for this legendary *mesorah* that was famous in Jerusalem at the time. A discussion broke our about this at a *pidyon haben* where [R' Yosef Chaim Sonnenfeld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Chaim_Sonnenfeld), the Rav of Jerusalem, was in attendance.

R' Sonnenfeld reportedly responded that although there is no source in classic literature for this idea, there is a *remez* in the *roshei teivos* of the pesukim relating to *Pidyon Haben*. (See Chochmas Chaim by R' Yosef Chaim Sonnenfeld, Parshas Bo)

> אכן אין שום מקור בספרים למאמר זה שהסעודה
> בפדיון הבן נחשבת לפ״ד תעניות, אבל יש בכך רמז בתורה בפסוק ׳וכל בכור אדם
> בבניך תפדה׳ – ׳אד״ם בבני״ך תפד״ה׳ נוטריקון ׳אם דבר מה בפדיון בן נהנית
> יחשב כאילו תענית פ״ד התענית׳.

R' Tzadok Hakohen writes (Pri Tzaddik V3, Pesach Sheni; see also [here](https://simla.otzar.org/download/file.php?id=994&sid=0d899742c0c49197516cadabbe4149e7)):

> רבותינו הקדושים אמרו שסעודת פדיון הבן היא כ- פ"ד צומות שהם לתקון פגם
> הברית

In Shu"t [Emek Yehoshua](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A2_%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9F) (Chelek 3, YD #18), the author quotes an oral tradition from his mentor tracing up to the [Arizal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Luria):

> ראה ראיתי בספר דברי שמואל לגאון הרב שמואל עמאר זצ"ל ,מרבני מרוקו בדף
> ב´ עמוד ב´ וזו לשונו: העיד לי החכם הרב דוד אדרעי שד"ר מעיר הקודש צפת
> תובב"א, ששמע מהרב המקובל הרב שמואל העליר זצ"ל, שקיבל מרבו המקובל הרב
> אברהם ביר זצ"ל שקיבל מרבו ורבו מרבו, עד הרב הגדול והקדוש האר"י החי
> זיע"א, שהנמצא בבית הפדיון בשעת הפדיון כאילו התענה פד´ תעניות, ובפרט
> בימי השובבי"ם יש תיקון גדול לכל הנמצא בבית, עד כאן שמעתי... ופשוט
> וברור שאם הרב שדי חמד זצ"ל היה שומע שמועה טובה כזו, היה מברך הטוב
> והמטיב

See also [Kaf Hachaim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Chaim_Sofer) (YD 249:14), who quotes the Pri Tzaddik.

Comment: שמהספרים (ראה אוצר פדה"כ פכ"א) על הגה"ק מאוסטרובצא זצ"ל, שהציקו לו על שמרבה בתעניות, שהרי יכול לצאת בסעודת פדיון הבן שנחשב כאילו התענה פ,ד תעניות, והשיב: הא דמקובל כאילו התענה פ"ד תעניות, הני תעניות הן כנגד עבירות שכתוב עליהם "כאילו" כגון: "כאילו עובד עבודה זרה", וכדומה. וחישב ומצא בש"ס ובחז"ל שיש פ"ד "כאילו" שכזה, וכנגד זה מועילה פדיון הבן, עכ"ד.

http://www.otzar.org/aspcrops/6291355-11708469650-13112011.asp

Comment: It is worth noting - the source attributed to the Arizal is regarding those who are *in the house during the Pidyon Haben*, not those who partake of the feast. This would not be a good source for those who try attribute this as the source for garlic & sugar distribution. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13461/what-is-the-source-for-the-garlic-and-sugar-at-a-pidyon-haben